# OpenSSL error in certificates

Tags: openssl, certificate

I try to create a client/server SSL with openssl following this method :
http://www.asafety.fr/projects-and-tools/c-client-serveur-ssl-tls-multiplateformes-avec-openssl/

I obtain on the server :

```
[+] Use TLSv1 method.
[*] Server's certificat and private key loaded from file.
[+] Server's private key match public certificat !
[+] Server listening on the 1337 port...
[+] Connection [127.0.0.1:60237]
[+] Cipher used : AES256-SHA
[-] No client's certificates
[+] Client data received : ClientName
```

And on the client :

```
[+] Use TLSv1 method.
[+] Cipher used : AES256-SHA
[+] Server certificates :
        Subject: /C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
        Issuer: /C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
[-] Server certificates X509 is not trust...
[+] Server data received : Enchante ClientName, je suis ServerName.
```

Do you know why I'm getting these messages :

"No client's certificates"

"Server certificates X509 is not trust..."

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

"No client's certificates"

did you see in the code any client certificates?

"Server certificates X509 is not trust..."

OpenSSL version? Whats the certificate you try to load?

Answer (score 0):

"No client's certificates" means that client code doesn't share a client's certificate. Client authentification is rarely implemented between a client and a server using SSL/TLS ; this isn't mandatory.

"Server certificates X509 is not trust..." means that the server's certificate received by the client isn't signed with a Certificate Authority. Your computer doesn't know the entire chain of trusted certificate server, but it is not fatal.